# issues with setting up crudbuilder for django

Tags: python, django

I'm thinking that this is a simple problem to fix.  The main error I'm getting when I runserver is

`crudbuilder.exceptions.NotModelException: No model defined in <class 'crudbuilder.abstract.BaseCrudBuilder'> class`

The github is located at https://github.com/asifpy/django-crudbuilder if you'd like to follow along.  After a `pip install` for `django-tables2` and `django-crudbuilder` I added both into my settings.py as such.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_tables2',
'my_project',
'crudbuilder', ]
```

In my models.py,

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class my_model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    gender = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

and in my newly added crud.py,

```
from crudbuilder.abstract import BaseCrudBuilder
from my_project.models import my_model

class MyModelCrud(BaseCrudBuilder):
        model = my_model
        search_fields = ['name']
        tables2_fields = ('name', 'gender')
        tables2_css_class = "table table-bordered table-condensed"
        tables2_pagination = 20  # default is 10
        modelform_excludes = ['created_by', 'updated_by']
        login_required=False
        permission_required=False
        # permissions = {
        #   'list': 'example.person_list',
        #       'create': 'example.person_create'
        # }
```

For some reason my django app doesnt like my `from crudbuilder.abstract import BaseCrudBuilder` from line 1 of crud.py, but it does recognize crudbuilder as a legitimate `INSTALLED_APP` 
The sources for crudbuilder were pretty minimal. Out of the 5 docs pages I found, they all share the same exact example doc.  I feel this may be a one line django error i've made.  Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Error says that, you didn't provided the correct model for your CRUD class.
Why are you giving `superman` as model for your crud class, where as your actual model is `my_model`.

Try to change `model = superman` to `model = my_model` in your `crud.py`

Comment: That's a typo. My apologies. I've edited the question.